# Background linear gradient not working in safari

Tags: css

I am trying to set a linear gradient background over an image and my code works in Chrome but not in Safari. Here is a full example of my code:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <img src="./assets/51a-front-img.png" draggable="false"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div:after{
  content: '\A';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* W3C */
}

img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: but you saw that your start and end color are the same?
i tried your styles (with adjusted end color) in Safari 8 on OSX Yosemite and it works. Which browser version did you test in ?

Comment: please provide full example. you're now (after your edit) using background properties on a pseudo-element (:after) which has no content and size so this could not work. neither in safari nor in chrome

Comment: I'm using Safari 9.0.1. I've adjusted the end color now and also forgot to mention that it's on an after pseudo element (not sure if that matters)

Comment: I have chrome and safari both open and it works in Chrome but not safari and yes sorry I hadn't added the content and size to my question (updated now)

Comment: tested your updated styles in el capita/safari 9.1 and yosemite/safari 8 and works in all cases. must be something else. we cannot step forward unless you share your full codes

Comment: Full example provided, appreciate the help!

Comment: Please take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qk7mh7j4/ is that what you want it to look like? then you simply need to add `left:0;` after the `top:0;` in `div:after`

Comment: Amazing, it worked! Thanks!

Comment: i added it as an answer so you can accept it and others can see the solution too. btw: if you would have posted the FULL codes at the beginning, this would have been fixed in 2 minutes. think of it for the next question ;)

Comment: Yes thanks, sorry I'm new to stack overflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The div:after needs to be positioned on the left edge (which chrome does by default). change your css to:

```
div:after{
  content: '\A';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* W3C */
}

img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```