# Background Linear Gradient not showing on Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a website and i'm having trouble with Safari.
I'm using a `background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient` that is working perfect on Chrome, Firefox, etc... but when it comes to Safari, the output is different.
It is showing only on half of the screen.

I'm using this style on the body:

```
body {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-40deg, #000,#333 50%, #f9f9f9 50%);
    background-size: auto 1200px;
    -webkit-background-size: auto 1200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I've tried searching for a solution, but so far nothing seems to work. I've tested changing the background size to cover but it doesn't give the output i intend, as well as setting `top: 0;` and `left: 0;` as shown in other question around stackoverflow, but that didn't work too.

The link to the specific page i'm talking about is this one: https://dashiofficial.com/product/test-product-01

Does anyone know the solution for this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background linear gradient not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489972/background-linear-gradient-not-working-in-safari)

Comment: _“It is showing only on half of the screen.”_ - and in that regard it actually behaves different, when you replace the gradient with a simple, solid background color …?

Comment: @pujasinghal it is not. If you read the answer in that question, you can see that i'm already using that. top: 0; left: 0; and it doesn't work. So please, don't say it is a duplicated post without reading both.

Comment: @04FS When i replace it for a background-color: #00; for example, it covers all the screen, which makes me think that it is a problem of Safari reading the -webkit-linear-gradient.

Comment: Okay, just wanted to make sure it’s not an issue where in certain situations body isn’t as “high” as one might think it should be. (But that mostly applies to pages with not enough content to cover one whole screen height to begin with.) I guess you put this through an auto-prefixer already, to ensure max. compatibility with older browsers? (First two online services I tried didn’t appear to add any more variations than what you already have, so I’d assume so.)

Comment: You no more need -webkit-, you can delete it. Top/left are also useless since there is no position involved

Comment: @04FS yes, already tried using auto-prefixers in hope it would add some code that would give me an answer, but it doesn't add any lines of code unfortunately. Changing it to cover instead of auto 1200px, places the gradient full screen, but i need it to have a certain height.

Comment: @TemaniAfif was trying different solutions. Removed that lines of code.

Comment: try this code: https://jsfiddle.net/6dxow3ak/

Comment: @TemaniAfif didn't work. The background got smaller.

Comment: I have reduced the height ... can you share a screenshot to show the difference between browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your website and was able to fix your safari problem. 
It has nothing to do with the gradient you defined for `body{}` but with the background-size for `.single-product{}`

Try to change

```
.single-product {
    background-size: auto 1060px;
}
```

to

```
.single-product {
    background-size: 100% 1060px;
}
```

It works for me in Chrome and Safari (not tested in Edge or Firefox).